# Network Design and Implementation

Tags: networking, active-directory, routing, ip-address

I am currently designing the network in my office, which is relatively small now but it plans to grow very fast.
The design is pretty much done, the problem is occurring during the implementation.
So the scenario is the following:

4 Subnetworks

- 10.70.0.0/24
- 10.70.1.0/24
- 10.70.2.0/24 with DHCP
- 10.70.3.0/24

and a DMZ network

- 10.10.10.0/24

One of the subnet has to have DHCP since is the one designed to host all the computers in the office. The hardware that we currently have is a firewall, that is our interface with the external network, this one has 5 interfaces one of which in getting the connection from the ISP.

Connected to this firewall there is then a layer 3 switch HP procurve 2650.

The point is that I don't know how to implement them. I have read around that I should also use VLAN, and it's fine but how can I connect the whole?

Moreover we have 2 Active Directory servers, which are part of the 10.70.0.0/24 network, and the firewall that is also the default gateway has the 10.70.0.1 address.

Comment: PS I am new to this work

Comment: So everything in the office right now will be connected to the same HP ProCurve switch, correct?

Comment: yes, except for 1 subnetwork 10.70.1.0/24 that will be running on another switch, adtran but is for IP telephony and it will come in the next future

Comment: Is the firewall providing DHCP or are you using Active Directory to do that? DNS could honestly be either the DHCP matters more because of the AD implementation.

Comment: Can you explain why you need this much initial complexity, especially when you're inexperienced in networking?  Most LANs grow with a single /24 that serves them well for years, well into the 100 workstation territory.

Comment: With my boss we tried to use on one AD the DHCP defining different Scopes, but the point is that we had some troubles with it, since giving for instance a 10.70.2.0/24 address to a machine and then giving the default gateway 10.70.0.1/24 it was causing troubles, because of the gateway on a different subnet. Maybe I could define static routes in the FW but is this a good approach?

Comment: @MixturaDementiae but why all the additional subnets?  I can see DMZ -- and that should be a built-in feature/network of your firewall -- but all those additional subnets just adds complexity and you'll have your hands full just managing a single /24 network.

Comment: @gravyface what you are saying is also true, but the point is that we are planning to expand our network and I think a good planning from the beginning could be a good solution for the future. OFC if I cannot find a way to do what I'm trying to do then I'll simplify everything.

Comment: You have the means to do so, but I would strongly recommend you make sure you're addressing today's needs before getting carried away with the future; if I had a nickel for every time a company said "we plan on growing quickly"... how many workstations do you have now?

Comment: If you want to use multiple subnets with one switch you will need to implement VLANs to be able to separate the traffic. This gets complex in a hurry depending on everything else you need to do. I went through this using SonicWall firewalls recently and it is not hard, just time consuming. It helps to have a functioning network however and move things one subnet at a time. As @gravyface said you might want to start simple and change things out later.

Comment: Forget the future for now. Do it (apart from the DMZ) with one subnet. It really isn't hard to expand it later if the need arises.

Comment: @MixturaDementiae how many workstations do you have now?

Comment: Now we have 30 clients and 15 servers...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not an experienced admin, setting up a brand new network with multiple subnets and VLANs is going to be very challenging.

**VLANS**

First off, let's explain VLANs.  In very basic terms, setting up VLANs on your switch partitions it into several separate switches.  So if I take a 48 port switch, I could setup two VLANs and have the equivalent of two 24 port switches.

Some firewalls will also support VLANs, and can be setup so it can talk to several different VLANs through a single interface, instead of having to run multiple cables.  The documentation for your firewall should tell you if this is possible and how to set it up.

**SUBNETS**

Each subnet (that wants to communicate outside of that subnet, to others or two the internet) will need a default gateway **inside that subnet**.  So your firewall will actually need to have IP addresses like 10.70.0.1, 10.70.0.2, 10.70.0.3, and 10.70.0.10.

Communication between the subnets can ONLY take place through the default gateway, so all traffic between subnets will be going through your firewall.  This can be a good thing, if you need to filter traffic between them, or a bad thing if your firewall is slow and becomes a bottleneck.

Instead of segmenting the network like this, I'd strongly recommend using fewer, larger subnets.  Start off with one for servers, and one for clients.  If you think you will grow quickly, use /16 subnets instead of /24.  You can still choose to use specific ranges for specific purposes.

**FUTURE EXPANSION**

If you use a /16 network, say 10.50.xxx.xxx, you can give all your server equipment addresses in the 10.50.0.xxx range and setup DHCP to hand out addresses in 10.50.2.xxx.  Since they are all on the same subnet, they can communicate with each other easily.  Later on, if you start running out of DHCP addresses, you can simply start handing out DHCP addresses in the 10.50.3.xxx range, without having to reconfigure ANYTHING.

Down the road, when you expand, have a bit more experience, and decide you need some servers to be isolated from the rest of your network, you can setup another interface on the firewall, and start using another range like 10.51.0.0/24 for those systems.  Then setup VLANs, or get a second switch.  That is easy to add later.  If you don't need it now, I wouldn't start with it.  The more complicated you make your network, the harder it is to troubleshoot.

If you really want to be clever, when you pick which address ranges to use for different purposes, choose ones that can easily be subnetted later, so you only have to change the subnet mask on everything if you want to isolate them.  That tends to be an easier task than changing server IP addresses.